# What is the best way to iterate through a long list of lists in python

Tags: python, sorting, memory, memory-management

I have a python list of lists which has around 10000000 rows and each row has 8 elements. I have noticed that iterating through this list and processing them is painfully slow. Somewhere in the program I also need to sort this list of lists using a specific key. I am using this in a System with 2gb RAM . What is the best way to do processing on such large lists??

**EDIT**

Lets assume data[] which has around 10000000 lists. I need to sort the data using each lists 0th element

So I am iterating through data as follows

```
for m in data:
```

and for sorting I am using

```
data=sorted(data, key=itemgetter(0))
```

Comment: How are you iterating through your list? Also, what is the criterion by which you want to sort?

Comment: Do you load this list into memory at once, or piece-by-piece?

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989251/alternatives-to-keeping-large-lists-in-memory-python

Comment: What are elements data types? What operations do you need to perform on them? Have you tried numpy arrays? To sort inplace, use `a.sort()` instead of `a = sorted(a)`

Comment: Some elements are string and some are float values.

Comment: Have a look at [Blist](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/), these are similar to lists but performs better than list as the size increases. 
http://stutzbachenterprises.com/performance-blist/sort-random-list

Comment: Honestly the "best" way may be to not have that monster list at all. Can your problem be reworked to be solved with chaining iterators?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what your sorting criterion is, I can't say much.

The most memory efficient way of iteration that I can think of is to use `itertools.chain`:

```
for element in itertools.chain.from_iterable(myLongList):
    print element
```

**EDIT**:

`sorted` creates a new list out of the old one. Use `list.sort` to do this in-place instead:

```
myLongList.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

if you want to iterate over the elements in each row and still be able to access items on either side:

```
for rowInd, row in enumerate(myLongList):
    for colInd, element in enumerate(row):
        print "myLongList[%d][%d] is %s" %(rowInd, colInd, element)
```

Comment: Yes, this is probably the best way to iterate through _items of inner lists_. This is important distinction, I think, as the OP may actually wish to have the list during the iteration also (although I hope he does not want that).

Comment: Actually, I need to access some previos and next values in the lists while processing a single element in the list.