# Sensible storage of 1 billion+ values in a python list type structure

Tags: python, list, memory

I'm writing a program that creates vario-function plots for a fixed region of a digital elevation model that has been converted to an array. I calculate the variance (difference in elevation) and lag (distance) between point pairs within the window constraints. Every array position is compared with every other array position. For each pair, the lag and variance values are appended to separate lists. Once all pairs have been compared, these lists are then used for data binning, averaging and eventually plotting.

The program runs fine for smaller window sizes (say 60x60 px). For windows up to about 120x120 px or so, which would give 2 lists of 207,360,000 entries, I am able to slowly get the program running. Greater than this, and I run into "MemoryError" reports - e.g. for a 240x240 px region, I would have 3,317,760,000 entries

At the beginning of the program, I create an empty list:

```
variance = []
lag =  []
```

Then within a for loop where I calculate my lags and variances, I append the values to the different lists:

```
variance.append(var_val)
lag.append(lag_val)
```

I've had a look over the stackoverflow pages and have seen a similar issue discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989251/alternatives-to-keeping-large-lists-in-memory-python). This solution would potentially improve temporal program performance however the solution offered only goes up to 100 million entries and therefore doesn't help me out with the larger regions (as with the 240x240px example). I've also considered using numpy arrays to store the values but I don't think this will stave of the memory issues.

Any suggestions for ways to use some kind of list of the proportions I have defined for the larger window sizes would be much appreciated.

I'm new to python so please forgive any ignorance.

The main bulk of the code can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/uM9vMtRb)

Comment: Never mind the memory requirements; your algorithm sounds like it'll never finish for larger datasets as your comparisons grow exponentially.

Comment: You should use numpy arrays instead of lists (wont solve your problem though, but will go faster). What does the rest of your kriging code look like? I assume you will get into problems there too.

Comment: @martijnpieters the windows will be fixed for a given program run - will this still cause an exponential issue? I'm experimenting with different window sizes and the resultant plots.

Comment: @usethedeathstar I'm actually only creating vario-plots and pulling out some stats as opposed to using them to drive any kriging algorithm. I've edited the original post so you can see the main bulk of the code.

Comment: @ChrisWills: Yes; your 120 x 120 window requires 42,998,169,600,000,000 comparisons, your 240 x 240 window would require 11,007,531,417,600,000,000 comparisons. At 1 billion comparisons per second that'd take 350 years to complete, vs. 1 1/3rd of a year for the 120 x 120 window. Roughly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think ChrisWillis is saying that he compares every point in this 240x240 window with each other and stores the result of each such comparison.  There are "only" 3,317,760,000 such comparisons, not the square of that number.

Comment: @ArminRigo: That'd be a little more manageable, but still the number of comparisons grows exponentially with increasing window size.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Quadratically, but not exponentially :-)

Comment: @ArminRigo: ick, yes. Except the OP appears to track 3 values per coordinates (120 * 120 ** 3 is 207,360,000, (240 * 240 ** 3 is 3,317,760,000).

Comment: In my opinion you ought to consider changing your approach altogether. Rather than computing an array of variances and lags and _then_ computing summary statistics such as bins etc, instead compute these summary statistics as you go along. In this way your maximum memory requirement would be the size of your running summary statistics.

Comment: @TooTone a new approach was exactly what I needed - there are no longer any lists in my code other than for the summary statistics - these are indeed calculated as I go along. To reduce run times, rather than comparing all pixels within a window with one another, I opted for a random sampling strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `array` module of Python.  It offers some list-like types that are more memory efficient (but cannot be used to store random objects, unlike regular lists).  For example, you can have arrays containing regular floats ("doubles" in C terms), or even single-precision floats (four bytes each instead of eight, at the cost of a reduced precision).  An array of 3 billion such single-floats would fit into 12 GB of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [PyTables](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables), a library wrapping the [HDF5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDF5) C library that can be used with numpy and [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Essentially PyTables will store your data on disk and transparently load it into memory as needed.

Alternatively if you want to stick to pure python, you could use a sqlite3 database to store and manipulate your data - the [docs](https://sqlite.org/limits.html) say the size limit for a sqlite database is 140TB, which should be enough for your data.

Answer (score 0):

try using heapq, import heapq.   It uses the heap for storage rather than the stack allowing you to access the computer full memory.