# Huge list on memory and file ( append, sort and write) without DB only flat file

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a huge list made of names ( in hexa ) every names lengh is from 2 to 40 lengh. 
After checking this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989251/alternatives-to-keeping-large-lists-in-memory-python)  on SO I could not manage to get it work.

The idea is to store the name every time I call the script ( easy append ) . 
to Be able to provide this list at will 
And finally to check ( either the name is on memory or in the file)  a name is on that list.

any thought  ?

Comment: If the list is so big that it's causing memory issues, why not use a sqlite db? Then you can just query it without needing to load all the data into memory.

Comment: Which specific part of [Alternatives to keeping large lists in memory (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989251/alternatives-to-keeping-large-lists-in-memory-python) that you tried did not work?

Comment: @SuperStew :  I do not want the DB.. I tried in the past, it is working... I want to get things in python only no other languages.

Comment: @MouIdri You can create/query a sqlite db entirely in python, unless you are counting the SQL statements as a separate language. Which, technically yea I guess they are, but like regex, they are important for any programmer to know.

Comment: @ SuperStew : it is actually linked to my code. I was using DB but I do need to use a file instead.  @ cowbert : Actually the thread is about a list of array and there is not action on sorting a given name from the file.

Comment: You said that you could not get https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989251/alternatives-to-keeping-large-lists-in-memory-python to work.  Which part did not work and how did it fail?

Comment: @MouIdri if you have a problem with sorting, then state that in your question. EDIT: I guess by "sorting" you mean searching.

Comment: You should use the DB.